# How are database tables implemented in MySQL?

Tags: architecture, data-structures, mysql

In the source code I suppose there's a table object, but how are the elements of a table stored in that object? With a vector, linked list, tree, or something else? I can never seem to find things when I download the source of huge programs with lots of classes and was just curious about this.

Comment: The elements *aren't* stored in that object. They're on disk. That's kinda the point.

Comment: Of course. I should have said something like references to said elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different table implementations that can be used in MySQL. Typically, disk-based trees are implemented using variations of a b-tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Comment: So inside the table object is a B-tree of pointers to file locations on the disk?

Comment: Yes, to locations within files.

Comment: "Transaction Processing: Concepts and Techniques" by Jim Gray (ISBN 1558601902) goes into more detail than you'll ever want to know about how relational databases work. Recommended.